# Verifier choose a random challenge to send to prover

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Could anyone explain me why the verifier in Honest verifier zero-knowledge Simulator, has to choose a random challenge to send to prover?

I have not understood well. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give us more context? Perhaps a link to the source.

Comment: for example in Schnorr's protocol https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_knowledge